# Using jquery in ReactJs

Tags: jquery, reactjs, virtual-dom

HTML:

JS:

```
var Counter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function() {
       return {
         list:['one','two'],
         flag: 1
       }
    },
    changeFlag : function() {
       this.setState({flag:2});
    },
    render : function() {
       var list = this.state.list;
       var flag = this.state.flag;
       return ( 
          <div>
              <ul id="list">
              {
                  list.map((item, index) => (
                      <li>{item}</li>
                  ))
              }
              </ul>
             <button onClick={this.changeFlag}>{flag}</button>
         </div>
      );
  }
})
ReactDOM.render( <Counter />, document.getElementById('content') );

setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('list').childNodes[0].innerText= 'three'
},2000)
```

I have initialized the list to 'one' and 'two'. Now I am directly updating the DOM using jquery and changed the value of 'one' to 'three' after a timeout of 2 seconds. Now, by clicking on the button, I am again the state, to re-render the component.

Now my question is if I directly change the DOM from 'one' to 'three', the virtual DOM should still be holding the value 'one', so next time If I change state, it will check virtual DOM against the browser DOM, and should update the browser DOM with the virtual DOM.In my case, the value 'three' still persists after clicking on the button, how is this happening?

Comment: Because virtual dom sees no change and determines there’s no need to change anything in actual dom

Comment: I believe it's comparing virtual DOMs, not what's in the real DOM. Reading the full rendered DOM tree on every render would be incredibly slow, since DOM access is slow

Comment: "so next time If I change state, it will check virtual DOM against the browser DOM" — why do you think it will?

Comment: It seems like bad practice to combine jQuery while uaing react. React does manipulate dom and expose rich API to use, why so you need to work also with jQuery?